# AVR Assembly code for UART, sending two characters over Serial?

Tags: assembly, avr, atmega32

I am just trying to send a character from my ATMEGA32A to Serial. Here is the code but its not working. I am unsure why because I think I am doing everything right. Can anybody help me fix?

(BAUD Rate: 9600)

```
.cseg
.org 0x00 

main:
ldi r16,0x80
ldi r17,0x25
call USART_Init

loop:
ldi r20, 0x86
call USART_Transmit
ldi r20, 0xFF
call USART_Transmit
rjmp loop


USART_Init:
; Set baud rate
out UBRRH, r17
out UBRRL, r16
; Enable receiver and transmitter
ldi r16, (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)
out UCSRB,r16
; Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit
ldi r16, (1<<URSEL)|(1<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0)
out UCSRC,r16
ret

USART_Transmit:
; Wait for empty transmit buffer
sbis UCSRA,UDRE
rjmp USART_Transmit
; Put data (r16) into buffer, sends the data
out UDR,r20
ret
```

I don't see anything in the Serial Terminal.
I am confident wiring is okay. Also set the 8bit data and 2-stop bit properly in the serial terminal settings.

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?  No data sent, wrong data sent, AVR catches on fire, or what?

Comment: To add to @jasonharper's comment, when it comes to software, it is important to be able to communicate clearly about how things fail or are failing; detail there is important.  Simply saying it doesn't work doesn't communicate effectively.

Comment: I don't see anything in the Serial Terminal.
I am confident wiring is okay. Also set the 8bit data and 2-stop bit properly in the serial terminal settings.

Thanks for queries. I also edited it in the post.

Comment: What serial terminal do you use? Are you sure it is able to display non-ascii characters (0x86 and 0xFF)? Try to send ascii first.

Comment: I have an Analog Discovery and I am actually using the waveforms application to read data. I believe it should support what we want.

Comment: Baudrate divider is incorrect. `0x2580` (in decimal `9600`) is not what divider should be. Refer to datasheet *20.3.1 Internal Clock Generation – The Baud Rate Generator* how to calculate divider depending on Fcpu and wanted baudrate.

Comment: Ah damn, how did I not see that. 
Thank you so much <3

Answer (score 2):

```
ldi r16,0x80
ldi r17,0x25
call USART_Init
```

It's 0x2580 = 9600, but **that's not how you initialitze a USART**. Instead, it's similar to initializing a timer: The higher the baud rate, the smaller UBRR.

For example, when the AVR runs at 1 MHz and you want 9600, then you need U2X = 1 and UBRR = 0xc = 12.

- Here is a small [JavaScript tool to compute UBRR values for ATmega](http://gjlay.de/helferlein/avr-uart-rechner.html).

U2X = 0 won't work with 1 MHz, because the resulting clock would have an error of 7%, which is too much for reliable UART operation.

If you use a reasonable assembler (like GNU as), then you can let the
assembler compute the UBRR values provided it is known at assembly time. In C, you would write something like:

```cpp
void uart_init (void)
{
    unsigned short ubrr = -.6 + F_CPU / ((16L - 8*U2X_BIT) * BAUDRATE);

    UBRRH = ubrr >> 8;
    UBRRL = ubrr;

    UCSRA = (U2X_BIT << U2X) | ...
```

where `U2X_BIT` is `0` or `1`, `BAUDRATE` is the desired baud rate and `F_CPU` is the clock frequency (in Hz) of the controller.

So better read the ATmega32 manual again.